# drawbacks of using custom divs as buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

Are there any known drawbacks to using a custom div as a button (with onclick), instead of a  object (such as iPads and other tablets not working properly, or too many divs slowing down pages, or any other problems)?

I'm not thinking specifically of using the button to submit a form.

Thanks!

Comment: How about [jQuery UI mobile buttons](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html)?

Comment: Accessibility issues?  Keyboard form navigation (via tab key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue would be to lose the semantics. HTML tags are not for the presentation only, they have a meaning and you should try to avoid violating it because your site won't play nicely with others. For instance, people that navigates on your site using screen readers might have some trouble finding out what actions they can perform on the page.